# Are variables passed in a URL tracked by Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, privacy

From what I understand, the data passed in POSTs from a form on a site is not tracked by Google Analytics. What about any variables that get passed in the URL, as in ?value=bla

Does value=bla get stored by GA?

If so, is there a way to not track variable info from the URL?

I am aware of the anonymizeIp for IPs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GA profile settings have a text field where you can enter query parameters that should be ignored. You can also set up an advanced filter to summarily excludes all query parameters (simply google "exclude query parameters google analytics", there a lot of tutorials on how th do this).